# I want to print the current podname in which my application is running in application logs in openshift

Tags: openshift

So my java application is running in several pod in openshift and I want to print the podname in application logs for some business purpose. Is there any way to do so? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to expose the Pod name to the application using the Kubernetes "Downward API". This can either be done by exposing an environment variable with the Pod name, or mounting a file that contains the name.

Here's the docs for doing so with an environment variable: https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/inject-data-application/environment-variable-expose-pod-information/#the-downward-api

Here's a trimmed down version of the example on that page, to highlight just the Pod name:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: dapi-envars-fieldref
spec:
  containers:
    - name: test-container
      image: k8s.gcr.io/busybox
      command: [ "sh", "-c"]
      args:
      - while true; do
          echo -en '\n';
          printenv MY_POD_NAME;
          sleep 10;
        done;
      env:
        - name: MY_POD_NAME
          valueFrom:
            fieldRef:
              fieldPath: metadata.name
  restartPolicy: Never
```

As you can see from the docs, there's a bunch of other context that you can expose also.

The equivalent docs for mounting a volume file can be found here: https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/inject-data-application/downward-api-volume-expose-pod-information/#the-downward-api